# Unable to understand warning

Tags: r

I would like to understand why the code below gives the warning message as shown.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(4, 5, 6)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
rownames(df) <- c("A1", "A2", "B1")
df$V <- "Others"
df[which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0)]$V <- "Primary"
```

> Warning message: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, which(grep(".*1$",
>   rownames(df)) >  :   provided 3 variables to replace 2 variables

```
length(which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0)) #2
```

Comment: If I am reading your intentions properly, your code is wrong. You want to assign "primary" all rows of `df$V` where the final character of row names is "1", right? If this is the case, don't use `which`. `df$V[grep(".*1$", rownames(df))] <- "Primary"` or `df$V[grepl(".*1$", rownames(df))] <- "Primary"`, using `grep` or `grepl` respectively, would be the proper syntax.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. This saved my day. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0)]
```

The line above will return df without last column(V), which means when using the `$V` R won't be able to find column V and you won't be able to assign any value in column V.

Comment: This explains what's going on but doesn't really answer the question

Comment: This actually helped Phil. So the fix will be df[which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0),]$V <- "Primary". That comma at the end of the expression is important

Comment: Or just move the `$V`, `df$V[which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0)]`.

Comment: I guess I got too used to data.table

Comment: @Phil It does answer the question. user3701522 couldn't understand why he was getting that error and I think I explained why.

Comment: @dvarelas Your answer definitely explains why the OP gets the error they do. But if someone reads this answer looking for help it's not immediately clear what they should do to correct the error (although they will understand what it is now and look for more help).

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `df[which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0), "V"]` or `df$V[which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0)]`.

```
df[which(grep(".*1$", rownames(df)) > 0), "V"] <- "Primary"

> df
   x y       V
A1 1 4 Primary
A2 2 5 Primary
B1 3 6  Others
```

Your positioning of `$V` is off.

Comment: Sure. I did not know about this syntax. Thanks